# Is SimpleCrypto dll is good and I can count on in real system to encrypt password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Is **SimpleCrypto dll** is good and I can count on in real system to encrypt password?

```
var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
var encryptpass = crypto.Compute(Password);
```

and if it is not what kind of encryption do ?

Comment: Whats wrong with `System.Security.Cryptography`? Regardless, this seems pretty opinion based, and dependent on "how good" your real system needs to be.

Comment: +1 to @BradleyDotNET, it's very opinion based. Also something to note; PBKDF2 is not encryption, it's a hashing algorithm. You should probably investigate the difference between hashing and encrypting before continuing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't encrypt passwords you should instead hash them. This is because encryption is two way where hashing is one way. You can use the C# HashAlgorithm to do this very easily:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx